# Trying to make connection of firebase in angular js and printing data in html but data is coming but not showing in html

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to call a Firebase function from my Angular app, and print that data in html. The data comes back from Firebase and when I `console.log` that it is showing that, but I am not able to show it in html body part.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.0/firebase.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.0/firebase-functions.js"></script>
</head>


<body ng-controller="prober">
    <pre>{{details}}</pre>
    <pre>{{prober}}</pre>
    <p>{{greeting}}</p>
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
      app.controller('prober', function ($scope) {
        scope  = $scope;
        scope.greeting = 'Hello, AngularJS!';
        scope.details = {};
        scope.sections = [];
        scope.activeSubject = '';
        scope.activeSubjectSection = '';
        scope.activeQuestion = '';
        scope.remainingTime = null;
        scope.testVisibility = 0;
        scope.requiredQuestion = {};
        scope.attemptedQuestion = {};
        let token = "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjdjZjdmODcyNzA5MWU0Yzc3YWE5OTVkYjYwNzQzYjdkZDJiYjcwYjUiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NlY3VyZXRva2VuLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vcHJvYmVyLWRldiIsImF1ZCI6InByb2Jlci1kZXYiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE3MDU0MDAxMTQsInVzZXJfaWQiOiJoZDk0ektta3JvWDRVbG5SMHdmMlVuOXNSRkYzIiwic3ViIjoiaGQ5NHpLbWtyb1g0VWxuUjB3ZjJVbjlzUkZGMyIsImlhdCI6MTcwNTQwMDExNCwiZXhwIjoxNzA1NDAzNzE0LCJwaG9uZV9udW1iZXIiOiIrOTE5ODk4OTg5ODk4IiwiZmlyZWJhc2UiOnsiaWRlbnRpdGllcyI6eyJwaG9uZSI6WyIrOTE5ODk4OTg5ODk4Il19LCJzaWduX2luX3Byb3ZpZGVyIjoiY3VzdG9tIn19.GmjY0xia63KLhF1AEMKrgyj_na83aBMU10cf41IkevZJn3lDCl8YWzcIzUL0fv9d1-6FmPqTQaMZ8sAMG8yLiEI7_8nexWnT0Hlz8JAREJPtDF7C8eJ1g64xl_HpaK2dw69o5mCM7566Zi3teLXPyYboh4_518jeZ_m0fSstFlz2aB0DKMmMDqRib061twY4USf6kny_SIkMoA2oZfXF-W-i3LVTv00JVbdMXfXAit-l4BDWGQq7AUSIHigfHA61AXzfcQTgBe7-JIh_4FH-lOVdgqUURf-S-Hrs-gG5GDf5-ra0M74akAim2c8CMMSpiljuWzeN8X8I5swREOlX-A" 
        var config = {
            apiKey: "apikey",
            authDomain: "domain",
            projectId: "project-id",
            storageBucket: "bucket",
            messagingSenderId: "messagingsenderid",
            appId: "appid",
            measurementId: "measurmentID"
        };
  
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
        var functions = firebase.app().functions('asia-south1');
        scope.userId = "userid";
        scope.paperId = "paperid";
        var leaderBoardFun = functions.httpsCallable('get_teacher_test_details');
        leaderBoardFun({ paper_id: scope.paperId, token: token, user_id: scope.userId }).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response)
            $scope.details = response.data.result;
        });
      });
    </script>
  
</body>

</html>
```

I don't know but it is problem of API response coming late and page load before the data come? it is possible?